# Who ruled the Khazars between Tong Yabgu to Irbis, if not Irbis himself?

Tags: steppe-nomads

Tong Yangu khagan finished his reign on 628. Who ruled the Khazars between Tong Yabgu to Irbis, if not Irbis himself?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: What is wrong with the information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Khazar_rulers)?  They suggest it was [Ziebel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tong_Yabghu) and [Bori Shad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6ri_Shad); it also lists different dates for Tong Yangu.  I also found [this source](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=tr&u=https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tong_Yabgu_Ka%25C4%259Fan&prev=search&pto=aue) which suggests Bagatur Sepi rules after Tong Yangu.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace thanks, from some reason, in the article "Khazars" Böri Shad isn't listed the list of rulers (which rather it starts with Irbis) so I think I might have missed the article due to that.